# EditorFor using different Validation Message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, editorfor

I have 3 Addresses using a single model which is `ContactAddress` using this in code:

```
public class ContactAddress
{
    [Required("Invalid address1")]
    public stirng Address1 { get; set; }
}
```

From the parent template

```
@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "validation" })
@Html.EditorFor(_ => _.HomeAddress)
@Html.EditorFor(_ => _.WorkAddress)
@Html.EditorFor(_ => _.OtherAddress)
```

From the editor template

```
<div class="large-9 columns left">
   @Html.TextBoxFor(_ => _.Address1, new { placeholder = "Enter text..."} )
</div>
```

This is fine. But the problem here is once the page validates, it shows duplicate Error messages.

it shows like this

```
 -Invalid address1
 -Invalid address1
 -Invalid address1
```

What i want here. is

```
 -Home Address: Invalid address1
 -Work Address: Invalid address1
 -Other Address: Invalid address1
```

Any suggestion on how to make the error message more specific per model without any drastic changes.

Comment: HomeAddress, WorkAddress and OtherAddress are type of "ContactAddress"
So changes to ContactAddress will reflect to all Concrete types. It's still the same you just changed the Message.


Thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: Neither here nor there, but using an _ for a lambda variable is... odd.  Heck, using a sole underscore for any kind of variable is odd.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a validation summary rather than individual validation messages, then there's not an easy way to do this when using data attributes.

You could customize this more if you used something like [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/), then you could add some type checks to determine which messages to use...